# Does an object alloc-inited in a dispatch_once block have to be autorelease in non-ARC mode?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, memory-management

For example, in current (12:05 AM Friday, January 10, 2014 PST) [Facebook SDK source code](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk), where the non-ARC is used,

> `FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy.m`
>
> `+defaultInstance`

```
+ (FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy*)defaultInstance {
    // static state to assure a single default instance here
    static FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy *sharedDefaultInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    // assign once to the static, if called
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedDefaultInstance = [[FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedDefaultInstance;
}
```

Would `sharedDefaultInstance = [[FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy alloc] init];` be a memory leak? Shouldn't it be `sharedDefaultInstance = [[[FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy alloc] init] autorelease];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The programmer is specifically creating a instance of FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy that will never be released since he's assigning it to a static variable of a class method.

It will be created once and only once, and shared by all instances of the class. It will never be released since a class itself is never destroyed (unlike an instance of the class).

Answer (score 1):

It is a singleton.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern It usually lives throughout all the application lifetime and should not be released